# live broadcasting video?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight-3.0, live

I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C# + Silverlight 3.0 + Microsoft Expression 3 + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0. I want to show my desktop lively to other users. In more details, suppose a case when a teacher is showing Demo or ppt on her/his desktop, the information on desktop could be broadcasted lively so that other users could see what the teacher is showing on her/his desktop.

It is better that end user could see the broadcast live information through browser. Any samples or document which could be helped to do this? I want to develop by myself using the technologies I described above, not using existing commercial software. :-)

BTW: when I say "broadcast", I do not mean using broadcast network protocol, I just mean multiple users could consume the live desktop information from the teacher.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas to develop Expression Encoder based live broadcasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several screen sharing products available to use:

- Livemeeting
- Webex
- WebConference.com

Would any of these work for you?

Additionally, you could Bing "Free Web Conferencing" and get a ton of freeware for this purpose.

**Edit**: Since you want to write one yourself check out the site

http://www.teknoportal.gen.tr/english/technology_news.asp?haber=385

Comment: I want to develop by myself if not too hard. Any suggestions or reference samples?

Comment: I noticed it is based on 3rd party, any solutions based on Microsoft technologies, like Silverlight, Expression, or IIS 7.0?

Comment: Any ideas to develop Expression Encoder based live broadcasting?