# Desktop Live Broadcast

Tags: php, html, desktop, live, broadcast

There is some way to display my desktop into a page, live? like youtube's hangout?
There is any freeware option?

links already seen:

[live broadcasting video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055377/live-broadcasting-video)

Thats is the main idea

"I want to show my desktop lively to other users. In more details, suppose a case when a teacher is showing Demo or ppt on her/his desktop, the information on desktop could be broadcasted lively so that other users could see what the teacher is showing on her/his desktop."

Not a webcam, no chat, only the desktop. Any options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is exactly what you want...
Easy to setup and they provide you with code to embed to your site.

**[www.zoho.com](https://www.zoho.com/meeting/embed-meeting.html)**

It has a free version as well which works like a charm but you are limited to 1 Host and 1 Participant and Duration limited to 1 hour. Paid version is not very expensive either

Answer (score 0):

Use VNC. If you need your viewers to see the shared desktop on a browser, VNC has a java viewer.

http://www.realvnc.com/support/javavncviewer.html